# How to define a Ember.computed helper that acts on the itemController of a Ember.ArrayController?

Tags: ember.js

I recently fell in love with the Ember.computed helpers. Especially the reduce computed ones like [computed.mapBy](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.html#method_computed_mapBy).

They work great when used with the `content` of an ArrayController like so.

```
App.People = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  //"content" is an array of App.Person objects.
  chosen: Ember.computed.filterBy('content', 'isChosen', true)
})
```

So lets say the `isChosen` property doesn't belong on the `person` model.

I could then define the `itemController` and create a computed property like so.

```
App.PeopleController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  itemController: 'person',

  chosen: function() {
    return this.filterBy('isChosen', true)
  }.property('@each.isChosen')

}); 

App.PersonController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  isChosen: false
});
```

This works, the `chosen` computed property returns an array based on the `personController.isChosen` property.

But this is not efficient because it runs the whole filterBy function every time a child changes.  Where as the `Em.computed.filterBy` helper adds and removes individual objects as needed.

Does anyone know how to define a Ember.computed helper that acts on the itemController of a Ember.ArrayController?

Comment: Are you sure chosen gets fired every time isChosen changes in an item?

Comment: Yes, here is a similar example http://jsbin.com/sunat/4  in this jsbin it should be possible to rewrite the "selected" property using a em.computed helper.

Comment: Yeah, it definitely would fire every time, the computed property says recalculate every time any dependency has changed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `@this` as the `dependentKey` to bind to the array of itemControllers.

```
App.PeopleController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  itemController: 'person',

  chosen: Ember.computed.filterBy('@this', 'isChosen', true)

}); 

App.PersonController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  isChosen: false
});
```

Pretty cool. Thanks to David Hamilton's presentation at the sf ember [meetup](http://www.meetup.com/Ember-SF/events/156014962/).